# java LocalExecute process exit value 127

Tags: java, linux

I'm writing a java program running at Linux. Below is the  java method

```
createHinted3gpFile (String localfile) {
    ArrayList<String> cmdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String hintedFile = localfile+".hint";
    cmdArray.add("cp");
    cmdArray.add(localfile);
    cmdArray.add(hintedFile);
    System.out.println ("Command ="+cmdArray);
    LocalExecute.exec(cmdArray.toArray(new String[1])); 
    cmdArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    cmdArray.add("/usr/local/bin/MP4Box");
    cmdArray.add("-3gp");   
    cmdArray.add("-hint");
    cmdArray.add(hintedFile);
    System.out.println ("Command ="+cmdArray);
    LocalExecute.exec(cmdArray.toArray(new String[1]));
```

}

and the output

> Command =[/usr/local/bin/MP4Box, -3gp, -hint, /opt/myproject/contents/29443b_3gp.hint]
>   [INFO] 10 Nov 03:23:00.467 PM http-8080-2 [myproject.transcoders.LocalExecute]
>   Process exitValue: 127

The Process exitValue should be 0 if everything went ok.
Since last week i get this 127 value! Any ideas about what happened?

Thanks
Antonis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/MP4Box, -3gp, -hint, /opt/myproject/contents/29443b_3gp.hint`

Perhaps these commas are the reason for your exit value.

How do you run this from command line? Perhaps this way?

`/usr/local/bin/MP4Box -3gp -hint /opt/myproject/contents/29443b_3gp.hint`

If yes, then you need to strip out the commas before execution.

**Edit**: from your comment, the commas are problematic.

I think you're overcomplicating your method. This should be easier on the eyes:

```
createHinted3gpFile (String localfile) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/MP4Box -3gp -hint " + localfile + ".hint");
}
```

Comment: from the cmd the command /usr/local/bin/MP4Box -3gp -hint /opt/myproject/contents/29443b_3gp.hint, works fine.

Comment: The commas are from the String[].toString() method and not part of the actual command.

Comment: The method above is perfectly right but i also want to keep the original 3gp file after the transformation! What about that?

Comment: @Antonis: before running above code, you should copy the original file somewhere else. Use `cp` to make a backup before running above command.

Answer (score 1):

127 means "command not found". `/usr/local/bin/MP4Box,` - is there a comma really?

Comment: Yes but that's the debugging output from println. The array in the debugger has no commas!

Comment: @Antonis: OK. try to execute the command manually from the command line, and then `echo $?` to display the exit code.